# Custom directive not working when it is provided in app.module

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have the following custom validator which is working as expected with no problems.

```
@Directive({
    selector:'[TestValidator]',
    providers:[
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting:TestValidatorDirective, multi:true}
    ]
})
export class TestValidatorDirective implements Validator{

    validate(control:AbstractControl):ValidationErrors|null {
       return  control.value == '-1' ? {'defaultSelected':true} : null;
    }   
}
```

When i remove the providers array from TestValudatorDirective and put it to the app.module.ts like below it is not working.

```
.....
providers: [
      { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting:TestValidatorDirective, multi:true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me, i am kind of confused.

Comment: directive is the part of declarations:[] so place it declarations section only i think it work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to move your validator to the `AppModule`. To be able to use your validator wherever you want it, you just need to ensure it is in the `declarations` of your module.

The `NG_VALIDATORS` token is injected into each Form Control by Angular. When this directive specifies something in the `providers` section, it's adding itself to that injection token for *that* particular field.

So it's not like adding a service to the `providers` section ... it shouldn't be in the module in this case.

But your module should allow the directive to be used, so needs to add the directive to the declarations:

```js
@NgModule({
  //...
  delcarations: [
    TestValidatorDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There's a good Thoughtram article which covers this topic really well: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Comment: "it's adding itself to that injection token for that particular field." this was the answer i was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.....
declaration : [
   TestValidatorDirective , < -- add here
   //... other components
 ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Directives are declared under `declarations` and not `providers`